# how to choose dynamic fetchSize in MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, select, dynamic, mybatis

We would like to set the fetchSize on particular query dynamically so that size-value can be passed at run-time based on the preconditions like total threads open etc..

Currently we are using MyBatis 3.4 ilbrary.

Below is the snapshot of query we are using in our application.

```
<select id="fetchDetails" resultType="ItemInformation" useCache="true" timeout="100000" fetchSize="50" statementType="PREPARED">

  SELECT * FROM PR_STAGE
  where 1=1
    AND release_date &gt;= sys_extract_utc(FROM_TZ(cast(TO_DATE(#{fromDate}, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')as timestamp),'America/Los_Angeles') )
    AND release_date &lt;= sys_extract_utc(FROM_TZ(cast(TO_DATE(#{toDate}, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')as timestamp),'America/Los_Angeles') )

</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a plugin.

```java
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.StatementHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Interceptor;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Intercepts;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Invocation;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Plugin;
import org.apache.ibatis.plugin.Signature;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.ResultHandler;

@Intercepts(@Signature(
  type = StatementHandler.class,
  method = "query",
  args = {
    Statement.class,
    ResultHandler.class }))
public class FetchSizePlugin implements Interceptor {

  private static final ThreadLocal<Integer> FETCH_SIZE = 
      ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> 100);

  public static void setFetchSize(int fetchSize) {
    FETCH_SIZE.set(Integer.valueOf(fetchSize));
  }

  @Override
  public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    Statement statement = (Statement) invocation.getArgs()[0];
    statement.setFetchSize(FETCH_SIZE.get());
    return invocation.proceed();
  }

  @Override
  public Object plugin(Object target) {
    return Plugin.wrap(target, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
  }
}
```

To register the plugin, add the following entry to the XML config ...

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin interceptor="pkg.FetchSizePlugin" />
</plugins>
```

... or call `org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration#addInterceptor()`.

Once the plugin is registered, you can set the fetch size by calling `FetchSizePlugin.setFetchSize()` before executing a query.

- If you don't call the method, the value set via `withInitial()` will be used.
- As it uses `ThreadLocal`, the fetch size you set will be applied to all the subsequent queries in the same thread unless you re-set another value.